# SQL FileTable Files in directory and HDD free space

Tags: sql-server, filetable

We have 2 folder in filetable directory. "$FSLOG" and the second one have stored files (my question is about second folder). Every time I open file. They are like temp files. Even if I delete the filetable rows they are still there.

For example I have 2 files in file table and 12 files in filetable directory. They consume free space.

What can I do for this problem?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51884/31995

Comment: my question is not about log folder.it is about the other folder that contains files that have size equal to My files